# Naming convention for "Page proxy" Component?

Tags: tridion

Tridion naming conventions are interesting because authors see names for:

- Schema
- Templates
- Categories and Keywords

I understand we can use Component fields to store page-related content `<meta name="keywords">`, `description`, and `<meta name="robots">`. This allows these fields to be translatable (versus page metadata) as well as managed by a distinct authoring group.

I might name this type of Component `SEO Info` or similar.

But we can also store non-SEO information such as the visible page heading (`<h1>This Heading</h1>`), navigation information, and other page-related settings/content (e.g. page-specific disclaimers).

**Do you have an author-friendly naming convention or approach for this sort of "Page proxy" Component?**

- Will `Page Meta` be confusing?
- Is `Page` too simple?
- Is `SEO` a misnomer if it includes non-SEO info?

Comment: Hi Alvin, you might consider posting this on http://superuser.com/search?q=tridion - There are no questions there yet related to SDL Tridion, but it might be a better spot for these kind of functional questions. It would be a good chance to create the 'SDLTridion' tag there rather than the old 'Tridion' tag we have here

Comment: I've just tried creating SDL-Tridion as a synonym for the tridion tag on here. You might consider voting on it (unfortunately it lowercased it for me!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think naming conventions are always tricky to come up with, due to the personal/subjective nature of them.

So, for your question, I think there is no one right way of naming it, but maybe something you and the client can agree on as a best descriptive name for the given situation.

Anyway, I'm kind of in favor of calling these Components `Page Info`, because they contain some kind of metadata/information about the Page. At the same time, `Page Meta` I think it's a bit confusing, since we are referring to a Component and can therefore be confused with actual Page metadata (defined on a Page).

I think the name `Page Proxy` is not bad either... or `Page Data`... It's very subjective indeed

**Edit:** `Page SEO` might be a misnomer, if the Component does not contain any SEO information. However, if there is some SEO data mixed with some `metadata` (such as heading, keywords, etc), I would say to put it all in the same SEO Component (so you don't have to create too many different tiny Components, which would make it more difficult to put pages together).

Comment: Update: Page Info is working fairly well for this, thanks and good points on the misnomers/confusing options with `Page Meta` and `Page SEO`. In terms of managing lots of tiny components, has anyone done a sort of composite/compound component extension? Or would that simply be the new UI? :-)